# Rotate image reduce quality

Tags: php, gd

I have a page where the user can rotate the images to the left and to the right.

The problem is that when the user rotates the image 4-5 times the quality is greatly reduced!

Am I doing wrong?

```
        $image_source = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_u);
        $rotate = imagerotate($image_source, $angle, 0);
        imageinterlace($rotate, true); //this is to create progressive jpeg
        imagejpeg($rotate, $path_u, 100);
        imagedestroy($rotate);
```

Comment: Unlike countless CSI episodes, image manipulation adheres to the principle of "garbage in, garbage out". If you send a garbled bitmap into an image manipulation function, you won't be able to get a Monet out of it. :)

Comment: Quality is being reduced because you're re-encoding it every time you save it, though you are using `100` for the quality setting. What happens if you don't call `imageinterlace`?

Comment: If I do not call `imageinterlace` it the same thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeatedly modifying and re-compressing an image (especially in JPEG, which is lossy regardless of the quality setting) is bound to eventually lead to multiplicative artifacts. You'd be better off keeping the original image, and when a rotation is requested, re-rotate the original, instead of saving over the original each time.

Comment: Thank you! it gets a little more complicated but it is definitely the best!

Comment: Not unusual for the best way to be a little complicated :)

Comment: How we can achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but in 2014 now, we can rotate jpeg pictures, not without quality loss, but by seriously minimizing it.

Imagejpeg method has a "quality" argument that helps set desired quality saving. 100 for the value is perfect.

I tried rotating multiple time the same image, and, the quality loss is not really visible to human eyes.

Here's the code.

```
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($pictureUrl);
    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
    imagejpeg($rotate, $pictureUrl, 100);
    imagedestroy($source);
    imagedestroy($rotate);
```